# Why do XSLT inserted scripts behave like asynchronous in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, xslt

I am using in-browser XSLT to generate HTML, `<script>` included. Firefox apparently behaves oddly in this case.

[The files below can be obtained and tried from there](http://laurent.caprani.free.fr/pub/FirefoxXsltAndScripts/). (Open [doc.xml](http://laurent.caprani.free.fr/pub/FirefoxXsltAndScripts/doc.xml) and look at the log messages in the console.)

Below is the test XSLT stylesheet I made. The XML source [doc.xml](http://laurent.caprani.free.fr/pub/FirefoxXsltAndScripts/doc.xml) is simply `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?><doc/>`. The transform creates both an inline and an external script:

```html
<html xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
  <head>
    <title>Firefox and XSLT inserted scripts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('inline, asynchronous? '+ document.currentScript.async);
        // -> "inline, asynchronous? false"
        // alert('inline, pause');
        function errorHandler(img) {
            img.src = 'http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-32-noshadow.png';
        }
        try {
            document.write("<p>Inserted</p>");
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
            // -> "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
        }
    </script>
    <p><img src="about:blank" onError="window.errorHandler?errorHandler(this):console.log('Too late for handling error!')"/></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The external script `script.js` is almost the same as the one inline:

```js
console.log('external, asynchronous? '+document.currentScript.async);
// -> "external, asynchronous? false"
// alert('external, pause');
try {
    document.write("<p>Inserted</p>");
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    // -> "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
}
```

The console displays:

```
19:21:14.435 "Too late for handling error!"             index.xml:1
19:21:14.477 "external, asynchronous? false"            script.js:1
19:21:14.478 "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
                                                        script.js:7
19:21:14.479 "inline, asynchronous? false"              index.xml:1
19:21:14.480 "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
                                                        index.xml:10
```

1. At first, the scripts seem synchronous, since `async` is false.
2. But in reality, they do *behave* asynchronously!

   - One cannot use `document.write`.
   - Callbacks (`errorHandler()` in my example) aren't immediately available.

Does anyone has a clue about what is happening here?

Comment: Your XSLT stylesheet is not a well formed XML document. However, could you specify how do you load the page? I guess you created a XML document with a `xml-stylesheet` precessing instruction, right? Do you load this file via a `file:` URL? What's its name?

Comment: I think you need to format properly it (use the backtick `). However, could you please answer to the other questions? You can also edit the question if there's too much to write.

Comment: I tried executing this stylesheet both from the file system (`file:`) and from a web server (`http:`). Same results.

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't reproduce the problem, I tried on Firefox 26.0 and one nightly build (29.0a1), on both I get `"inline, asynchronous? false" 
"TypeError: document.write is not a function"`

Comment: I've put my samples [online](http://www3.bell.net/laurent.caprani/FirefoxXsltAndScripts/index.xml). I added the console messages to the question. I use Firefox 26.0. I can't understand why you get `document.write is not a function`. I get a more sensible error.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla's XSLT processor implementation creates a result tree and renders that directly so using `document.write` is not supported, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F. Other client-side XSLT processor implementations might feed the serialized transformation result to its HTML parser, in that case document.write works.

If you want to output stuff with your scripts inside XSLT then you need to use the DOM methods to create nodes and insert them. See http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013122801.xml for an example.

Comment: This does explain the error with `document.write`. But there remains a mystery about the order of execution. The `onerror` handler is mostly fired before the `<script>` are executed. They look pretty much like asynchronous scripts (although not marked as such).

Comment: @LaurentCAPRANI, you might consider to ask on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ respectively a forum or mailing dedicated to Mozilla development what they think about the behavior of `script` elements in XSLT generated HTML documents.